# C# WPF is freezing Progressbar during Datagrid populate

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, user-controls, progress-bar

I have a slow query. It is taking a time after running. I want to display progressbar during the thread. I tried to use backgroundworker for this.

I am using usercontrol which are my panels children. the picture below is main page. When i click to Page 1 my dockpanel will have page_1 usercontrol.

[Mainwindow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZY9H0.png)

```
    private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        page1 pg = new page1();
        Container_Panel.Children.Add(pg);
    }
```

I am trying to show indetermined progressbar while opening the page1 usercontrol. I use these codes for this.

```
    private BackgroundWorker bw = new BackgroundWorker();

    private void bw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
       Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() =>
       {
          populate();
       }));
    }

    private void bw_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        prg2.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;    
    }

    private void UserControl_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                bw.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
                bw.DoWork += bw_DoWork;
                //bw.ProgressChanged += bw_ProgressChanged;
                bw.RunWorkerCompleted += bw_RunWorkerCompleted;
                bw.RunWorkerAsync();
                prg2.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

And the method which has datagrid codes below

```
private void populate ()
{
            using (SqlConnection con= new SqlConnection(connectionstring))
            {
                con.Open();
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                SqlCommand cmd= new SqlCommand("Select ...", con);
                cmd.CommandTimeout = 0;
                SqlDataAdapter _dadapt= new SqlDataAdapter();
                _dadapt.Fill(dt); 
                con.Close();
                dataGrid1.itemsSource = dt.DefaultView;
            }
}
```

The code is working and i can see prg2 (progressbar) became visible . But it is freezing till the end of the query. After that the other process hide is working and progressbar is hiding. But i want to make progressbar indeterminate during the query.

Or Can i make a progressbar outside of the containerpanel which is working with clicking mainwindows button.

I am trying to solve this issue and i tried too much application but can't solve.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
private void bw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        populate();
    }

private void populate ()
{
            using (SqlConnection con= new SqlConnection(connectionstring))
            {
                con.Open();
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                SqlCommand cmd= new SqlCommand("Select ...", con);
                cmd.CommandTimeout = 0;
                SqlDataAdapter _dadapt= new SqlDataAdapter();
                _dadapt.Fill(dt); 
                con.Close();
                bw.ReportProgress(90,dt.DefaultView);
            }
}
```

Implement report progress event

```
private void bw_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
       if(e.ProgressPercentage == 90)
       {
              dataGrid1.itemsSource = (DataView)e.UserState;// don't remember if it's the same property but there's a property check
       }
}
```

Comment: Sorry but it is giving same problem as i got

Comment: Try now as background worker implements report progress we don't need dispatcher

Comment: Could you please let me know what's freezing because no part of the above causes UI to freeze

Answer (score 1):

You should be using a Task for this, as a Background worker is not needed. Also, you'll need to use async/await so that the Visibility gets updated correctly without affecting the UI.

Also note that con.Close() is not needed, as it's already wrapped in an using statement.

```
private async void UserControl_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        prg2.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;

        dataGrid1.itemsSource = await GetDataAsync();

        prg2.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden; 
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}

private Task<DataView> GetDataAsync()
{
    return Task.Run(()=>
    {
        using (var con = new SqlConnection(connectionstring))
        {
            con.Open();

            var dt = new DataTable();
            var cmd= new SqlCommand("Select ...", con);
            cmd.CommandTimeout = 0;

            var dadapt = new SqlDataAdapter();
            dadapt.Fill(dt); 

            return dt.DefaultView;  
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 private BackgroundWorker bw = new BackgroundWorker();

 private void bw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{

      populate();

}

private void bw_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    prg2.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;    
}

private void UserControl_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            bw.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
            bw.DoWork += bw_DoWork;
            //bw.ProgressChanged += bw_ProgressChanged;
            bw.RunWorkerCompleted += bw_RunWorkerCompleted;
            prg2.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            bw.RunWorkerAsync();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }


 private void populate ()
 {
        using (SqlConnection con= new SqlConnection(connectionstring))
        {
            con.Open();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            SqlCommand cmd= new SqlCommand("Select ...", con);
            cmd.CommandTimeout = 0;
            SqlDataAdapter _dadapt= new SqlDataAdapter();
            _dadapt.Fill(dt); 
            con.Close();
            Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action  (() =>
                {
                dataGrid1.itemsSource = dt.DefaultView;
                }));
        }
  }
```

Comment: Given error: An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in WindowsBase.dll but was not handled in user code 
Additional information: The calling thread must be STA,  
because many UI components require this.

Comment: do you try to change a property of a control in the asynchron method ? Could you post the content of your populate  method ?

Comment: I missed. Now it is including populate.

Comment: You should remove this code from the asynchron methode. : dataGrid1.itemsSource = dt.DefaultView; You should fill a list in this method and bind to your grid at the bgWorkerCompleted method.

Comment: Or you can call :   Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() =>
       {
dataGrid1.itemsSource = dt.DefaultView;
} in the methode populate

Comment: i made the changes. i moved DataTable dt = new DataTable(); outside of the method. Then in bw_RunWorkerCompleted method i made dataGrid.itemsSourc = dt.DefaultView. But nothing changed.

Comment: private void populate ()
{
            using (SqlConnection con= new SqlConnection(connectionstring))
            {
                con.Open();
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                SqlCommand cmd= new SqlCommand("Select ...", con);
                cmd.CommandTimeout = 0;
                SqlDataAdapter _dadapt= new SqlDataAdapter();
                _dadapt.Fill(dt); 
                con.Close();
       Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() =>
       {
          dataGrid1.itemsSource = dt.DefaultView;
       })); 
            }
}

Comment: change your method populate like the post above.

Comment: I edited my first answer, you can take all the code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Xceed BusyIndicator control from nuget, type

```
Install-Package Extended.Wpf.Toolkit
```

on Package Manager Console. In your View reference and add the control

```
<wpfex:BusyIndicator IsBusy="{Binding IsBusy}" DisplayAfter="0" BusyContent="{Binding IsBusyMessage}"  />
```

and bind it to your modelview, anyway you must to do the query asynchronously

Answer (score 0):

I would try something like this

```
    // ##############################################################################################################################
    // Properties
    // ##############################################################################################################################

    private BackgroundWorker _BackgroundWorker = new BackgroundWorker();
    private readonly string _ConnectionString = "LoremIpsum";


    // ##############################################################################################################################
    // Events
    // ##############################################################################################################################

    private void UserControl_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            _BackgroundWorker.DoWork += _BackgroundWorker_DoWork;
            _BackgroundWorker.RunWorkerCompleted += BackgroundWorker_OnRunWorkerCompleted;
            _BackgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
            prg2.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }

    private void _BackgroundWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Result = _HardWork();            
    }

    private void BackgroundWorker_OnRunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs runWorkerCompletedEventArgs)
    {
        if(runWorkerCompletedEventArgs.Result != null)
        {
            dataGrid1.itemsSource = (DataView)runWorkerCompletedEventArgs.Result;                
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Failed to load data..");
        }
        prg2.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
    }

    // ##############################################################################################################################
    // Private Methods
    // ##############################################################################################################################

    private DataView _HardWork()
    {
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(_ConnectionString))
        {
            con.Open();
            DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
            SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand("Select ...", con) {CommandTimeout = 0};
            SqlDataAdapter sqlDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
            sqlDataAdapter.Fill(dataTable);
            con.Close();
            return dataTable.DefaultView;
        }
    }
```